# Twitter-Bootstrap-3 on Wordpress Jquery not loading

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am trying to hook up my custom theme created on Bootstrap 3 and installed onto the latest version of WordPress  -working fine but there's an issue with it not being able to hook up to the Jquery library or my JS files.

I have usually been able to achieve this by doing:

```
<script src = "<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
```

But it is just failing on me altogether.

So I have WordPress on the root of the Dir with my files sitting in the theme folder as expected. Short of ideas now :/

Side note: I have tried placing these into both header and footer files and also injecting the JavaScript straight into the HTML but nothing...

Comment: you checked console??

Comment: Try linking to a hosted version to see where the issue lies: <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

Comment: Thanks Roy! Seemed to do the magic!

Comment: so your url was wrong in direcotry

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The recommended way to include both, jQuery and bootstrap.js would be a function in your functions.php.

```
function load_styles_and_scripts(){
    wp_enqueue_script('jquery');
    wp_enqueue_script('bootstrap-scripts', get_template_directory_uri().'/js/bootstrap.min.js');
}
```

and then calling it at the end of the file

```
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'load_styles_and_scripts');
```

this way, you load the jQuery file which already comes with wordpress. As the call to enqueuing bootstrap.js comes after jQuery, this should work. You can also add dependecies in the `add_action`-call. This allows you to make sure, that dependencies are loaded in the right order.

For further information, have a look at http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_enqueue_script